# напечатать отчет по конфигурации и состоянии компьютера

Tags: linux, windows

Руководство поставило задачу напечатать отчеты по конфигурации и состоянии компьютеров. Отчет включает в себя:

- Название материнки
- Кратко о процесоре(название, архитектура, сокет, частота, кол. ядер, )
- Количество слотов памяти
- Количество установленных плашек
- Общий объем памяти
- напряжение по линиям 3.3 5 12
- информация о жестких дисках (модель, объем, S.M.A.R.T.)
- сетевые устройства

Сейчас информация собирается вручную, потом перепечатывается уже в файл. На один компьютер уходит более часа монотонного труда. Отсюда вопрос

**Как автоматизировать создание отчет кастомизацией вывода?**

Comment: Для начала — как именно вы собираете вручную?

Comment: По велению левой пятки, от компьютера к компьютеру метод сбора данных меняется. выделяются два способа, визуальный и программный . Первый применяется совместно с тех обслуживанием. разбираем корпус смотрим что написано на материнской плате, какие слоты и чем заняты и т.д. Потом включаем компьютер заходим в биос, смотрим напряжения, проверяем показатели вольтметром(под нагрузкой). дальше запускаются программы проверки памяти и hdd. Последняя выдает смарт Второй запускаем Speccy или lshw,smartctl и копируем оттуда данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот например. Без вольтажа.

```
#!/bin/bash
# version:0.03

echo -e "\"cpu\"
{
`dmidecode -t processor | grep -E "(Version|Core Count|Socket|Max Speed)"`
}
\"mb\"
{
`echo "$(dmidecode -t baseboard | grep "Manufacturer" | sed "s/\tManufacturer: //") - $(dmidecode -t baseboard | grep "Product Name" | sed "s/\tProduct Name: //")"`
}
\"gpu\"
{
`lspci | grep VGA | sed \"s/^.*: //g\"`
}
\"hdd\"
{
`egrep -o \"Model.*$\" /proc/scsi/scsi`
}
\"ram\"
{
`dmidecode -t 17 | nawk '{if ($0==\"Memory Device\") I+=1 ; if ($1==\"Size:\") {sub(/\t/,\"\",$0) ;SIZE[I]=$0 }  ; if ($1==\"Speed:\") { sub(/\t/,\"\",$0) ; SPEED[I]=$0 };  ; if ($1==\"Type:\") { sub(/\t/,\"\",$0) ; TYPE[I]=$0 } }   END { for(i=1;i<=I;i++) print SIZE[i]\" \"SPEED[i]\" \"TYPE[i]}'`
}
\"os\"
{
`cat /etc/issue.net`
}
\"hostname\"
{
`hostname`
}
\"mac_addr\"
{
`ip a | awk '/link\/ether/ {print $2}'`
}
" | sed 's/^$//g'
```

Comment: ifconfig - утилита не поддерживается более чем 10лет: **ip address** из пакете iproute2

Comment: Поправил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Какие еще утилиты пробовали?

- dmidecode - инфа о материнке биосе проце памяти
- lspci - сетевые карты, раиды
- lshw - прочее и все предыдущее
- smartctl - накопители
- lm-sensors - напряжение и температура

**полная автоматизация**

*затраты на разработку и тесты - 10-20ч*

Берем Ubuntu ISO, модифицируем под себя preseed в который включаем скрипт с фильтрованной информацией выхлопа предыдущих утилит. Организуем PXE сервер, к которому подлючаем зоопарк серверов (из вопроса делаю вывод о разнообразном железе).
Машины грузятся с PXE и скидывют выхлоп по lftp.

**частичная автоматизация**

*1-3ч на подготовку и тесты*

Используя уже готовый скрипит, фильтрующий выхлоп, создаем загрузочный ISO на флешке со свободным разделом. Обходим ножками весь зоопарк и сохряняем результаты в свободный раздел.